# Templates external linkage does't work

Tags: c++, templates, linkage

Standard says that template names have [external linkage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

My question is: "**Why isn't there a linker error when I declare the same templates in two .cpp files and compile this files together?**"

Global functions names have external linkage like templates names. That's why I suggest that they should have similar behavior. But as for functions there is nothing strange and the linker produces an error, but as for templates somehow there is no error.

**temp_1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

// error because of external linkage
// void eq_f(){}


template<class T>
void my_func() {
    std::cout << "1!";
}
```

**temp_2.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

// external linkage
// void eq_f(){}

template<class T>
void my_func() {
    std::cout << "2!";
}

int main() {
    my_func<int>();
    return 0;
}
```

**command:**

```
clang++ temp_1.cpp temp_2.cpp -std=c++17
```

Comment: read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: @SaufenmitProgramming ok, thanks. try to find answer.

Comment: You might also want to read what templates actually do, because right now, `temp_1.o` only has some static constructors because of `<iostream>`, there is no `my_func` in there.

Comment: @Rakete1111 this line "external linkage ... names of all templates not listed above " from cppref confused me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**temp_1.cpp** doesn't produce any code because template is compiled for the implementations, the only class the compiler can find for the `main` is in **temp_2.cpp**.

That's why you don't get any error.

It is somehow can be compared to a macro: the template class is like the `#define`, the implementations is like using the macro in the code, at the end of the cpp the "macro" is undefined, only the implementations of it are left.

**EDIT:**

As I wrote above, the template itself doesn't generate any type, that's why it can't be linked. the type definition is when you use the teplate with a typedef or variable declaration.

for example: `template<class T> class vector` is a template class, it doesn't make any type definition and doesn't produce any code.

When you use it : `vector<int> vInt;` or `typedef vector<int> vInt_t` the class will compiled only for `class T=int` if you use it again for other type it will be compiled again for that type too.

only used templated type may have a linkage, means it will be the same type when you define it again. the type `vector<int>` may have external linkage, (means can be return from library or dll, etc.)

Comment: Ok. 
But when is the external linkage of template names use?